# How to compute time-space maps automatically?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, qgis-plugins, time

I am looking for a way to produce a time-space map in QGis or ArcGIS. See an example [here](http://www.spiekermann-wegener.com/mod/time/time_e.htm).

As input data, I have a city in the centre of Germany with travel times to some other cities around it. I am looking for a way to deform the "normal" geographic map of Germany to show the travel time instead of distance.

Any idea on how to do that with QGIS, ArcGIS or other GIS ?

Comment: cartograms? QGIS http://anitagraser.com/2010/11/13/creating-cartograms-with-qgis-cartogram-creator/

Comment: do you want to move things closer to / further away from the city, depending on travel times, and warp the map around the repositioned cities?

Comment: Yeah, thats pretty much my intention. Citys come closer/further depending the travel times between them

Comment: I think you will have more luck getting an answer to this if you reduce the scope of your question to either QGIS or ArcGIS for Desktop.  At the moment I suspect it is falling between the cracks of the two sub-communities.